# Optional property on class deleted after write

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I am working on an application, written in Swift 3.0.2 with Realm 2.4.2, targetting iOS 10.0.

I have this data model:

```
class User: Object {

    var company: Company? = Company()
    dynamic var password = ""
    dynamic var email = ""

    func persist() {
        let realm = try! Realm()
        try! realm.write {
            realm.add(self) 
        } 
        print(company)
    }
}

class Company: Object {
    dynamic var id = ""
    dynamic var name = ""
}
```

In order to save the user's data, I use this code:

```
let user = User()
user.email = "john@apple.com"
user.password = "hey"

user.company?.name = "apple"
user.company?.id = "12"

// here, if I check with debugger, all variable are properly filled
user.persist()

// here : company is = nil
// it is nil at the 'print(company) 
// it is not nil before
```

Can someone explain why it does this?

Comment: Hmm, I just noticed one of your comments. Are you _only_ checking the value of the `company` property via the debugger?

Answer (score 0):

Your `company` property must be declared with the `dynamic` modifier to make it possible for Realm Swift to provide a getters that retrieves values from the underlying Realm file. Without the `dynamic` modifier, the Swift compiler generates access to the underlying instance variable, which does not contain any data for objects loaded from a Realm file.

Comment: Hi,thanks for the feedback. unfortunatly, it is not possible :

Comment: I obtain an error : Property cannot be marked dynamic because its type cannot be represented in Objective-c.

Comment: I also tried to add @objc before the Company class delcaration, without success (annoying to have to make several comment here... instead of a normal answer...)

Comment: `dynamic var foo: Class?` is how [Realm Swift requires that to-one relationships be declared](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#to-one-relationships). If the Swift compiler is saying that your `Company` type cannot be represented in Objective-C it seems like there must be more its definition than what you've shared. Can you make sure that the code you've shared in your question matches what you're testing with?

Comment: Hi. Yes, I just verified. I believe that it is a bug in Realm. what do you think ? the only way, for me, to save Company class, is to set it as a List<Company>....

Comment: If you can distill the bug to a self-contained example that we can run, please do [file a bug against Realm](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/new).